# FastReport Master-Detail ClientDataSet Show Master Records with Empty Detail

Tags: delphi, fastreport, tclientdataset, delphi-10-seattle

I have 2 `ClientDataSet` Master and Detail and I use FastReport to print the report
the problem is FatReport print only Records with details
I have some Master record doesn't have details and I still want to show them in report
So how can I print every record in Master `ClientDataSet` even when the detail `ClientDataSet` is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property `PrintIfDetailEmpty` in MasterData. It is false by default. Try to set it to true.

Comment: it work as needed, Thank you,  Do you know how can I access `MasterData` by code from my main application?

Comment: Use TfrxMasterData(frxReport1.FindObject('MasterData1')).PrintIfDetailEmpty := True;